# How can I get OpenFileDialog to focus on the "files box", and not the "name box", when opened?

Tags: c#, winforms

When the dialog box opens the focus is on the name box. I have to tab like 10 times to get to the files, and arrow down to the one I want.

I am using keyboard not mouse.

```
private void LoadFileNow()
{
   OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
   Open.Filter = "GCode Files|*.ngc";
   Open.Title = "Select a GCode File";
   // Show the Dialog.
   // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and
   // a .ngc file was selected, open it.
   if (Open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Assign the GCode FileName to Var.
      GV.GCodeFile = Open.FileName;
      string f = "";
      f = String.Format("{0}{1}", "GCode File: ", Open.FileName);        //Change Ver. 4.0.1.1
      label6.Text = f;
      TextBox.LoadFile(Open.FileName,  RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
   Thread.Sleep(500); //Wait a moment while file loads.
}
```

Comment: Last time I tried (but it's been a while since I had to), a single `Shift+Tab` combination brought me to the file list.

Comment: Is this a program that's only for your own personal use? Because if not, opening a standard Open File dialog that looks just like every one in pretty much every single program in Windows, but acts differently, makes for a really crap user experience.

Comment: Brian, that is nothing but rude.  I have a system that requires to be ran 100% by keyboard.  Mr. Hamidi, this only goes backwards tabbing... and still takes several clicks.  Yes it is a standard open file dialog.

Comment: I just tried Hamidi's method on a WinForms open file dialog and it worked with 1 Shift+Tab.

Comment: If OpenFileDialog is your own class, try wiring up the OnLoaded event, giving the control you want to focus a name, then when the dialog has loaded try focusing the control (i.e. ListBox1.Focus() or whatever you name the file display control).

Comment: If you just start typing the filename there should be an autocompletion that comes up, then you use down arrow to focus on it and then hit enter.

Comment: Shift+Tab  2 times, then down arrow and back up arrow.  Just to select the first file.

Comment: @jeffserv - It isn't rude when you consider that your question shows _very_ little research or effort in asking.  Try Google, 'OpenFileDialog set focus', for example.

Comment: Brian, I spent over an hour looking through other articles. I found nothing that showed what I needed.  If you have an answer, then answer, but don't be rude... to people who are attempting something new.

Comment: Derek, I tried what you are saying.  Not a bad answer... as I have to make a tutorial... of how to do this.  If we know the first letter of the name of the file.  Then this will work. I will accept this is the best solution so far.

Comment: @jeffserv When the dialog opens you want focus to be in the box with files/folders correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I get this right you want to focus the file selection window when your dialog box opens? Oh you are gonna love this one haha. Might be other ways but this works :-p. Only tested in Windows 7. You might have to change the control search.

Lets p/invoke some stuff

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string lclassName, string windowTitle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

method that will let us get child controls of parent

```
private static List<IntPtr> GetAllChildrenWindowHandles(IntPtr hParent)
{
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
    IntPtr prevChild = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr currChild = IntPtr.Zero;
    while (true)
    {
        currChild = FindWindowEx(hParent, prevChild, null, null);
        if (currChild == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            break;
        }
        result.Add(currChild);
        prevChild = currChild;
    }
    return result;
}
```

here is the method we will run in a thread right before you open your dialog

```
private void FocusFileDialog()
{
    bool windowFound = false;
    while (!windowFound)
    {
        IntPtr od = FindWindow(null, "Select a GCode File");

        //found main dialog
        if (od != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr od1 = FindWindowEx(od, IntPtr.Zero, "DUIViewWndClassName", null);

            if (od1 != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr od2 = FindWindowEx(od1, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);

                if (od2 != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    List<IntPtr> results = GetAllChildrenWindowHandles(od2);

                    results.ForEach(hwd =>
                    {
                        IntPtr od3 = FindWindowEx(hwd, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);

                        if (od3 != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            IntPtr found = FindWindowEx(od3, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);

                            if (found != IntPtr.Zero)
                            {
                                SetForegroundWindow(found);
                                SetFocus(found);
                                windowFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you will open your dialog

```
new Thread(FocusFileDialog).Start();
using (OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    //your stuff here
}
```

Attached is from Spy++ might help you understand. What is selected is what we need the pointer for.

[image]